# Property of a self-related vector field on a Lie group

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

I meet with this problem in my assignment.

Now G is an n-dimensional connected smooth Lie group and $ω^i$ i=1,...,n are the left invariant basis of smooth vector fields on G, **i.e ,$w^i$ ,i=1,...,n are linearly independent at any point g∈G and for any i, $w^i$ is a left invariant vector field**.
  Assume **σ: G → G** is a **smooth** map and for i=1,....n , $w^i$ is **σ-related to itself**. I want to prove : 
**σ=$L_{σ(e)}$** .

I tried several methods but could not get any inspiration. I would apperciate if anyone could give a hint of the solution.

Comment: Hi, could you provide a definition for $\sigma$-related to itself?

Comment: @k76u4vkweek547v7 Ok. [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2702648/basic-question-about-related-vector-fields-and-pushforwards) You could see it here in the problem statement.

Comment: do we know here if $G$ is connected (or alternately that $\sigma$ is injective)? if not, it seems possible to construct counterexamples: Take your favorite Lie group and consider its product with $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. The quotient map has the property you describe, but is clearly not a left translation.

Comment: @Kajelad Sorry, I think I omitted the connectivity here. I have edited it. I have figured out that σ is a local diffeomorphism by the condition of the problem. But I don't know how to do next.